# How can I destroy the session set using saveSessionSnapshot() in codeception?

Tags: php, session-variables, codeception

The session remains alive even after logout.

This is my login file.

> public function loginAsAdmin($wpUserName, $wpPassword) {
>
> ```
> $I = $this->tester;
>
> $I->amOnPage('/wp-admin');
>
> if ($I->loadSessionSnapshot('login')) {
>     return;
> }
>
> $I->seeElement(self::$wpUserNameField);
> $I->fillfield(self::$wpUserNameField, $wpUserName);
>
> $I->seeElement(self::$wpPasswordField);
> $I->fillfield(self::$wpPasswordField, $wpPassword);
>
> $I->seeElement(self::$wpSubmitButton);
> $I->click(self::$wpSubmitButton);
> $I->wait(5);
>
> $I->saveSessionSnapshot('login');
> ```
>
> }

Details

Codeception version: 2.2.10
PHP Version:
Operating System: OS X
Installation type: Composer
List of installed packages (composer show) I am Using lucatume/wp-browser package for codeception

This is my Suite configuration:

> class_name: AcceptanceTester modules:
>
> ```
> enabled:
>     - \Helper\Acceptance
>     - WPWebDriver
> config:
>     WPWebDriver:
>         host: 'hub-cloud.browserstack.com'
>         port: 80
>         browser: 'firefox'
>         url: ''
>         adminUsername: ''
>         adminPassword: ''
>         adminPath: '/wp-admin'
>         capabilities:
>            'browserstack.user': ''
>            'browserstack.key': ''
>           'os': 'OS X'
>           'os_version': 'sierra'
>           'browserstack.debug': 'true'
> ```

This works fine I don't log out but in some test cases, I need to log out to validate some assertions. There it creates the problem.

Is this a bug? Can't we destroy the session upon logout?

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain PHP functions inside the Codeception tests. 
This should work, if you call it from inside the test:

```
session_destroy();
```

Comment: I actaully found the work around for the same. :) The session can only be destroyed using this function only if that is created using session_start()

Comment: If you found a solution, please post it as an answer. :)

Comment: This is what I used the fallback parameter. I passed 3rd arg when I want to save the session.

public function loginAsAdmin($wpUserName, $wpPassword, **$saveSnapshot = true**)
{
$I = $this->tester;

$I->amOnPage('/wp-admin');

if ($I->loadSessionSnapshot('login') && $saveSnapshot) {
    return;
}